# how to fix onChange event won't work in input react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

onChange event won't work in input react when trying to call a function! any help please
I'm getting values using watch()
my point is when onChange in input I want to get the whole value

```
const Valid = () =>{
    let Username = watch("Username")
  console.log(Username)

    const {data} = useQuery(CHECK_AVAILABLITY, {
      variables:{Username},

      }
      
    )




 <form>
            <Input onChange={Valid} type="text" {...register("Username")} placeholder="Username " />

            <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <Button type="submite" >Sign Up</Button>

          </form>
```

Comment: I would suggest including the name of the form library you are using, this is not just standard React.

Comment: const Valid = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);

You want the value from the input?

Comment: import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { gql,  useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

Comment: no i dont want to get the value i want to execute the function when onchange

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using react hook form.
you can use the watch and the useEffect method

```
let Username = watch("Username")

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('username value', Username);
},[Username]);

return(
  <form>
      <Input type="text" {...register("Username")} placeholder="Username" />
      <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <Button type="submit">Sign Up</Button>
  </form>
);
```

Comment: yes i try it but i want when the input is done  get the full value

Comment: if you want to have the final value, once the user ends the edition on the username input, you will need to use some focus event, but it's tricky, the user can change the focus then come back to the input and do changes, a better option is use the on submit method, and then you validates all your data.

Comment: <Input  type="text" {...register("Username",{onBlur: () => Valid()} )} placeholder="Username " />
this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to put it like that

```
<Input onChange={(e) => Valid(e.target.value)} type="text" {...register("Username")} placeholder="Username " />
```

and then get the variable in the params of the Valid function

exemple :

```
const valid = (username) => {
console.log(username)
}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: you didn't get me right i want when it's done inputting i get the full value because if i use your method I'll keep getting values with anything is typed

Comment: so i can send it in query and your method it will send a lot of request to the server contains any letter you've typed